# IDE within docker image?

Tags: docker

In a attempt to make our dev environment easier to clone we are moving to docker. Now I understood the docker workflow as for code and dependencies, but I am not sure what to do about the dev tools we use.

So what is the best practice as for dev tools (e.g. IDE, git client GUI, sublime text...)? Should they be embeded in images and containerized, or should they be run from the host (with all the installation hell that we know)?

I have looked in the docker hub and there seems to be attempts at embedding dev tools in containers but I am not sure if it is mainstream...

Also, in the case where the tools are run from the host (not the container), how should the code shared the host and container? Should a host folder be mounted as a volume (in which case the code would not belong to the container)?

EDIT: obviously the intent is not to force anyone to use the containerized tools, it's just to way to make it easier to install a minimal common dev environment...

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: Let developers choose their own tools. Just use docker for the code and let the developers use vim, emacs or nano or whatever they want.
For sharing code you run the container with the -v option where you link a folder on the host machine with one in the container. Then just use whatever editor and tools on the host machine.

Comment: I doubt moving rich-GUI tools into docker containers is such a good idea; GUI application has to interoperate with window manager and desktop environment (for obvious reasons), which conflicts with docker container isolation

Comment: You should checkout http://www.eclipse.org/che/ which is a docker based IDE

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing several workflows for the containers policy regarding tools it emerges that for complex dev environment it is useful to keep 2 images (i.e. 2 Dockerfiles). One including the basic dev tools and a bare one with no tools (both Dockerfiles being generated by a bash script and a common source to avoid redundancy).

The reason for this policy to give guidelines (and an easy learning curve) to new comers and flexibility to experts.

This approach provides the best of both worlds at virtually no cost.